# Jenkins pipeline not polling mercurial branch

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins version 2.89.4

I have a pipeline that should checkout my code and test it everytime a commit is pushed.

```
    stage('Code checkout') {
        dir("${env.HG_NODE_DIRECTORY}") {
            checkout([$class: 'MercurialSCM',
                credentialsId: '...',
                clean: true,
                disableChangeLog: true, 
                installation: '(Default)', 
                source: 'ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/team/project'])
        }
    }
```

I have a webhook on my Bitbucket project that should trigger this builds, but they are not triggering.

The only job that triggers is one I created as a test, where I have my checkout configured the old way, directly into the job configuration, with no pipeline.

Is this a bug? Can I somehow trigger this kind of pipeline by SCM polling?

EDIT: I had to create a job with "normal" SCM configuration to then trigger the other jobs.

Comment: Are you trying to get scm polling working or start this build when triggered by bitbucket? Those are very different problems, but it seems like you're conflating them.

Comment: @StephenNewell I want to have a job configured with pipelines to get triggered when someone commits something. As it is, the only way I can achieve this is by having another job configured with the sole purpose of polling my repository and triggering the other jobs. Just by putting that "Code checkout" step is not working.

Comment: I just had a similar problem myself, and managed to solve it after a while. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430020/jenkins-mercurial-plugin-does-not-detect-changes/50677204#50677204